# Which of the following is most efficient one and why?

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-5.5, php-7.1, memory-efficient

Following is the query which retrives all the order rows from the orders table

```
 $orders = auth()->user()->orders;
```

**or**

```
 $orders = Order::where('user_id',auth()->id())->get();
```

**or**

```
 $orders = \DB::table('orders')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
```

If orders table 100 000 rows then which of the above method is ideal to use?

Comment: The first two should be (to my reading) executing essentially identical things behind the scene. The third will skip turning the results into Eloquent models, which will be a tiny bit more performant but also reduce the usability of the `$orders` result. I'd use #1, as it's the cleanest code and it's highly likely you don't need to optimize this carefully unless you've covered like a hundred better optimizations first.

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p are you writing this query in model or controller

Comment: In controller @karthik

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Laravel you can use **toSql** method to compare the queries and see which one is the most optimized query like this:

```
$sql=auth()->user()->orders()->toSql();
```

But in the example above we see generally all of them are the same:

```
//First
"select * from `orders` where `orders`.`user_id` = ? and `orders`.`user_id` is not null"

//Second
"select * from `orders` where `user_id` = ?"

//Third
"select * from `orders` where `user_id` = ?"
```

As you see the second one and the third one are totally the same but the first one has an extra **and** statement and it's more reliable so I think the execution times are not different and you'd better to use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

compare to laravel eloquent DB:: class is faster way to retrieve data from database but in our case we manage a application in structure way and its depend on your coding standard and module management.

i suggest to use :

```
$sql=auth()->user()->orders()->toSql();
```